# Query takes too much time when added new column to table and set index on it

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have added a new column to table which contains lakhs of records. and created composit index with three column (one newly added + two existing column)

for exampl. in table TBL there are two columns say col1 , col2

I have added new column col3 to TBL and created composit index (col3, col1, col2).

Now for all records col3's value is NULL. when I select on this table, It takes too much time..

Any idea, what ma I doing wrong., I check query plan it is using index

Answer (score 0):

Using index is quite expensive when the table has small number of rows or there is too much same values in the index.

Check the query plan for costs, not using index.

Also it seems that you are adding new row on the run (the nulls) which might suggest that your schema is denormalized.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved using Statistics Gathering by using

> DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS

Thanks @Jan for your view..